# Bind Gender with Radio button in Create and Edit in MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show Gender Male Radio Button and Female Radio button on create and on Edit the selected radio button if male then male should be selected if Female then female should be checked.
Model

```
[Table("tblUserData")]
public class test
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Create View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>test</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

How do I replace the

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
```

With

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model=>model.Gender)
```

It asks for one more parameter where do I get it from as its a Bit in sql if its 0 then Gender is Male if 1 then Female.
Same I want to do it for edit so that user can see the Gender and update it through radio buttons.

Comment: You mean that your world view splits people into MALE and OTHER? I serious suggest you take a look at [ISO IEC 5218](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218) before you get slapped.

Comment: You want one radio button or a group of radio buttons ?

Comment: @Shyju Two Radio Buttons Gender Male Radio Button Female Radio button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your razor view is strongly typed to your class,test

```
@model test
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, true)
    <span>Male</span>

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, false)   
    <span>FeMale</span>

    <input type="submit" />    
}
```

For your edit view, the same code will work as long as you are sending a valid object of `test` to your view. Based on the value on the `Gender` property, it will select the corresponding radio button.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var vm = yourSbContext.tests.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==id);
   if(vm!=null)
   {
     return View(vm);
   }
   // to do  : Return a Not found/404 response/view
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for writing true and false?? in the second parameter.